# Inline assignment on IF statement

Tags: c#

Is it possible to "short-circuit" assignment and validation into an IF statement..

Something line this..

```
if ((Match m = Regex.Match(data, pattern)).Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["myField"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Heinzi answer is correct, but I don't advise  you to do that. If you have multiple conditions your if will become unreadable. In the end what is you benefit from this ?

Comment: I have to process a data file and need to look for a list of expressions so there will be multiple expressions each on its own `if ()` statement

Comment: You can do that properly with only one Match variable and multiple bool variables, but if you feel that this is looking better go on. Mark the answer of Heinzi as correct.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In general: assignment yes, declaration no:

```
Match m;
if ((m = Regex.Match(data, pattern)).Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["myField"].Value);
}
```

Declaration expressions [have been suggested](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/254) but have not been implemented yet.

However, depending on your C# version, there are workarounds for your particular use case.

---

**C# 7:** Since C# 7, arguments to `out` parameters in a method call can be declared inline:

```
string s = "123";
if (int.TryParse(s, out int i))
    Console.WriteLine($"{s} has been parsed as {i}.");
else
    Console.WriteLine($"Unable to parse {s}.");
```

so you *could* work around your problem by designing a custom `RegexTryMatch` method:

```
public static bool RegexTryMatch(string input, string pattern, out Match match)
{
    match = regex.Match(input, pattern);
    return match.Success;
}
```

an use this pattern when calling it:

```
if (RegexTryMatch(data, pattern, out Match m))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["myField"].Value);
}
```

Adding such a method to the .NET class library is [currently being discussed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30308).

---

**C# 9**: The pattern matching features of C# 9 allow for a solution which is very similar to what you proposed:

```
if (Regex.Match(data, pattern) is { Success: true } m)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["myField"].Value);
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
if (Regex.Match(data, pattern) is {} m && m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["myField"].Value);
}
```

Comment: And for those looking for null check specifically, it turns out that `if (GetObjectThatMayBeNull() is {} obj) {...}` is enough to both assign and check obj is not null! Note that like `obj is not null`, this bypasses user-defined equality (so if this matters you may want to add `&& obj != null` - I think I'll do that on Unity)